# after login when click hardware back button navigated to login page how to prevent it in ionic 4

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4, angular9

```typescript
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      //new page add
      {
        path: 'home',
        children: [
          {
            path: '', loadChildren: () => import('../AllPages/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule)
          },
          {
            path: 'new-arrival',
            children: [
              {
                path: '',
                loadChildren: () => import('../AllPages/new-arrival/new-arrival.module').then(m => m.NewArrivalPageModule)
              },

              {
                path: 'product-item-list',
                children: [
                  {
                    path: '',
                    loadChildren: () => import('../Allpages/product-item-list/product-item-list.module').then(m => m.ProductItemListPageModule)
                  },

                  {
                    path: 'product-details',
                    children: [
                      {
                        path: '',
                        loadChildren: () => import('../Allpages/product-details/product-details.module').then(m => m.ProductDetailsPageModule)
                      },
                    ]

                  }
                ]
              }


            ]
          },
```

Comment: How do you navigate to your next route after the login ?

Comment: After login when i got status==1 then i use -->> this.router.navigate(['/tabs/home']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ionic NavController instead of Angular Router.
Then, use the `navigateRoot`method.

> Going **root** means that all existing pages in the stack will be removed, and the navigated page will become the single page in the stack.

```
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
...
constructor(private navController: NavController) {}
...
this.navController.navigateRoot('/tabs/home');
```

Comment: Thanks for Your answering

Comment: @Vinod accept my answer if it solved your issue, thanks!